# What is the meaning of the expression "my likeness" in the phrase below?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"I sued American Apparel because they calculatingly took my name, my likeness and image and used them publicly to promote their business."

I tried every translation for "likeness" in Portuguese I could find and none of them seems to make any sense.

Comment: [*Likeness*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/likeness): "**1** : COPY, PORTRAIT; **2** : APPEARANCE, SEMBLANCE; **3** : the quality or state of being like : RESEMBLANCE." Since the sentence already uses *image*, it likely means that they took the person's style and mannerisms. But I'm now curious why none of the Portuguese translations would result in any of these senses.

Comment: Google gives: a semelhança
 
a imagem 

 a aparência
 
o retrato
 
a similitude

o semblante.   a aparência seems the closest.

Comment: Hi, thank you guys for helping me on this. I found various translations for "likeness" in Portuguese on google translator and also other dictionaries. I think the main problem is that he used the word "image" in the phrase so I was thinking that the word "likeness" should or could be related in this case to something completely different. I think the explanation given about someone taking other person's style and mannerisms, which I haven't found anywhere else, can be the answer I was looking for. Anyway, thanks again and please forgive me for my poor English.